# How to plot members of the Geometry module

Tags: python, plot, sympy

I need to plot line segments based on a midpoint, an angle (slope) and a length. I know how to define and plot a segment using a linear function; I'm trying to switch to [Segment2D](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/lines.html#sympy.geometry.line.Segment2D) in order to take advantage of its built-in methods.

```
from sympy import plot, sin, cos, pi, Point2D, Segment2D
x, y, angle, length = 1, 1, pi/6, 0.5
dx = length * cos(angle)
dy = length * sin(angle)
p1 = Point2D(x-dx, y-dy)
p2 = Point2D(x+dx, y+dy)
segment = Segment2D(p1, p2)
p = [{'args': (x, y, 'ro')}]
plot(segment, markers=p)
```

This results in an error:

> t = plot(segment, markers=p)
> series = [LineOver1DRangeSeries(*arg, **kwargs) for arg in plot_expr]
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

It seems Segment2D similar classes defined in the [geometry module](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/index.html) cannot be plotted directly. I can't find anything relevant in the documentation about how to handle Segment2D with `plot` or to convert it into a function which can be plotted by SymPy.

Any help appreciated at this point. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Line` can tell you its equation and can be instantiated from a `Segment`. An equation can be solved for `y` as a function of `x` (and that can be plotted):

```py
>>> s=Segment((0,0),(1,3)) 
>>> Line(s).equation(x,y)
-3*x + y
>>> solve(_,y)
[3x]
>>> plot(_[0])
```

Comment: That works. The line can also be created directly as `Line(p1,p2)`. I wonder why `equation` method is part of [Line](http://lidavidm.github.io/sympy/_modules/sympy/geometry/line.html#Line) and not part of the base class `LinearEntity`. This would make it available in `Segment` too.

Comment: The equation of the line contains points that are not on the segment. It would have to be a Piecewise formula as a function of x (or y, if vertical). I'm not sure how well Piecewise plots.

Comment: That's right, in my case I only need the segment for plotting purposes, the line is fine for other uses (intersection, perpendicular) and I can `plot` with a range for `x`,

Answer (score 1):

`sympy.plotting` is currently unable to deal with geometric entities .

However, the external package [SymPy Plotting Module](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) provides the [`plot_geometry` function](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/functions.html#spb.functions.plot_geometry). For example:

```
from sympy import *
from spb import *
var("x")
plot_geometry(
     Circle(Point(0, 0), 5),
     Ellipse(Point(-3, 2), hradius=3, eccentricity=Rational(4, 5)),
     Polygon((4, 0), 4, n=5),
     Curve((cos(x), sin(x)), (x, 0, 2 * pi)),
     Segment((-4, -6), (6, 6)),
     Point2D(0, 0))
```

Note: seems like today StackOverlow has problems with image upload. You'll have to check the documentation (linked above) to visualize the output of the function.

Comment: Thanks, as usual your answer is clear. Unfortuntely SymPy Plotting Backends doesn't work well with my configuration, Spyder freezes when starting to plot and the kernel must be restarted very often.

Comment: Would you be able to open an issue on Github providing more information about your configuration? OS, python version, Spyder version, error traceback if any...